# Issues deploying SSRS related to permissions

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssis

I'm tryingto deploy a package (from a Visual studio 2017 ) and I'm receiving this error:

> ### TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services
>
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined
> routine or aggregate "**deploy_project_internal**":
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: **A required privilege is not held**
> by the client System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:     at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerProcess.StartProcess(Boolean
> bSuspendThread)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.DeployProjectInternal(SqlInt64
> deployId, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 projectId, SqlString
> projectName) . (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 6522)
>
> For help, click:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.7016&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=6522&LinkId=20476

I thought it would be related do any permission but, the user being used for the deployment is sysadmin in the instance.

we have 3 sql servers, and 2 of them could have the package deployed, but for some reason I can't deploy in the third one.

permissions ar all the same for everyone since they're in the same OU.

I can't find any good spot over the internet pointing me to , what permission I should take a look.

MS page for ssis permissions points me to where I was initially, and other forums point me to " restart sql server" and other crazy stuff.

I already changed the ssis service account, changed the agent account, I set the necessary permissions on every dcom option...